# How to wrap a function from an inherited class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I want to use my own class `RetrySession` that is inherited from `requests.Session`, but with more robust try/else checking (for non-200 status codes, timeouts, etc.) and extra logging around the `get()` function.

```
# retry_session.py
import requests
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Oversimplified...
class RetrySession(requests.Session):
    def get_(self, url, **kwargs):
        logger.info(url)
        return self.get(url, **kwargs)
```

Is there any way to keep the original function name of `get()` without like temporary copying the function? Right now, I'm doing something like:

```
from retry_session import *

# Logging defined here

s = RetrySession()
# Would like to do s.get(...) instead of s.get_(...)
r = s.get_("https://httpbin.org/get")
```

Comment: Please try to write valid Python code, `s = new RetrySession()` would throw a syntax error

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oops. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `super()` to call the method from the superclass, also there is no `new` keyword to instanciate object

```
class RetrySession(requests.Session):
    def get(self, url, **kwargs):
        print("Requesting", url)
        return super().get(url, **kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = RetrySession()
    r = s.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
```